# Filter Results Via checked box in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, if-statement, eloquent

i am making a blog system and i am trying to include a feature where you can make posts visible and hidden. for this im trying to create a filter where i can show the hidden ones on the home page if a press a button. i have linked the checkbox to my database using this

```
        {{Form::label('hide', 'Hide')}}
        {{Form::Hidden('hide','0')}}
        {{Form::checkbox('hide', '1')}}
```

and then linked to the postController with

```
$post->visible = $request->input('hide');
```

which stores the value in the database, seeing as it was either 1 or 0 i used the binary type in mysql
now when displaying my blogposts i use this

```
@section('content')
<h1>Posts</h1>
<li><a href="/posts/create">Create Post</a></li>
@if(count($posts) > 1 || count($visible) == 0) //this was an attempt to fix the issue as if it's unhidden the value us 0 
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="well">
        <h3><a href= "/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h3>
        
            {{$post->Body}}
        
        <small> Written on{{$post->created_at}}</small>
        </div>
        <div>
            <small>Expires on{{$post->expiration_date}}</small>

        </div>
    @endforeach
    {{$posts->links()}}
@else
    <p> No posts </p>
@endif


@endsection
```

could you see any way around this, ideally i would have button that refreshes the results between hidden and unhidden i tried this by making a completely new if statement that runs off a button but seeing as i cannot even sort it without the button in the if statement i didn't include the code.
thanks in advance and sorry for any silly mistakes in code

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is `$visible` and how does this relate to an "individual" post being visible or hidden?

Comment: $visible is just an attribute a user has such as user_id but it only has two states, on and off or 1 and 0 so i basically i want a way to filter by $visible using 1 or 0

Comment: so why are you calling `count` on it? and if it is an attribute a user has what does that have to do with filtering posts?  are you trying to say that a post has an attribute named visible and you want to filter posts by their individual value for visible?